# PDFGeneratorAPI - generating the signature

Tags: sha256

PDFGeneratorAPI seems like a quite powerful tool for generating and designing online PDF-documents. But i spent some time to generate the correct signature key in c# and translate the PHP-example they have on the website:

```
   $key = 'abcdefghijk';
   $secret = 'abcdefghijkabcdefghijk';
   $workspace = 'OB1234';
   $resource = 'templates;


  $data = [
    'key' => $key,
    'resource' => $resource,
    'workspace' => $workspace
  ];
  ksort($data);

  $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', implode('', $data), $secret);
```

The first problem is, that the PHP ksort does sort the array not in the same way as c#. I don't know exactly why, but i got a string array where "t" was sorted before "O". Is it sorting based on ASCII codes?

And i struggled a bit to find the right translation in c#

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    public string CreateSignature(string secret= "abcdefghijkabcdefghijk", string APIKey= "abcdefghijk", string resource = "templates")
    {

        List<string> _apiStringArray = new List<string>() {APIKey, resource, "'OB1234" };

        // _apiStringArray.Sort();

        string _apistring = String.Join("", _apiStringArray.ToArray());
        string _signature;

        var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
        byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(_apistring);
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
        {
            byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            _signature =  BitConverter.ToString(hashmessage).Replace("-", "").ToLower();


        }

   return _signature;

    }
```

But still wondering about the sorting

Florian